# How to check status of Android hotspot using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, networking, hotspot

I'm building an app that requires a user to enable their hotspot. Is there any package to get the info of the hotspot of the device? if there's no package, how can I achieve it then? should I write android specific code (kotlin) for that?

I have checked the connectivity_plus package but it only provides information about WiFi and Mobile data. I also checked the wifi_iot package but it's mostly deprecated and has a lot of compatibility issues.